# How to validate a Username field which can take an email as username but also can use alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a username field which can take in either alphanumeric characters (including underscore and hyphen) or a user's email as username. I added a RegEx validation for alphanumeric characters and an email with an 'OR' condition but that didnt seem to work. I can validate for invalid characters and it can recognize when I input an email but it passes the wrong email like 'test@test'. This is the RegEx I used

```
"/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/|"+ @"[\w\s\.@_]*"
```

Comment: Why not use two regular expressions (one for email and one for username) and OR the tests?

Comment: Validating emails can be very complicated. Would a simplified version work? Like `anything@anything.anything`?

Comment: for e-mail you need 2-4 characters for domain extensions:

Comment: Great now your regex won't let me use email+label@gmail.com - good job!

Comment: @techfoobar that is what I attempted to do ....

Comment: @AmitApollo: No, f.e. `.museum` and `.travel` exist.

Comment: You can adjust the 2,4 constrains to 2, xx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two regex expressions and use || for truth validation.

You need to append +.[A-Z]{2,4} to the email one for the proper domain extensions. it accepts 2-4 character domain extensions. You can adjust the 4 accordingly.

```
  ^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

Comment: Thank you @AmitApollo I actually forgot to include the other '|' in my statement. It works fine now the first expression checks for valid alphanumeric characters and the second one checks for emails.

Comment: `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_{|}~ Space` and `"(),:;<>@[\]`,`International characters above U+007F` are valid characters in email...this regex would **reject** valid emails..

Answer (score 1):

An email is valid if you can send a mail to it..

Even space is a valid character in email.The only required thing in email is `@`

So your regex would be

```
 /^[\w-]{3,16}$|^[^@]+@[^@]+$/
```

Your regex `[\w\s\.@_]*` to validate email could cost you the loss of 50% of your potential customers :P.

---

Have a look at these articles

- [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)
- [Simple Explanation of E-mail address format (RFC 822)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html)
- [Email Address format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)
- [RFC 822 Standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)

Bottom line is these standards have never been followed so its better to stick with
`^[^@]+@[^@]+$`